# TSX Parsing error:Expression expected on arrow function

Tags: typescript, tsx

How can i solve this error?
`TS1109: Expression expected.`
I'm new to typescript and I don't understand why is error popping up.
Any suggestions please?

```
  const checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = () : boolean => {
    return if (localStorage.getItem("logged-in") === "true" ) {
      return <LoggedInMp/>
    } else {
      return <NotLoggedInMp/>
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code. The `return` in front of the `if` is wrong and the return type of your function may also be off. The first `return` is causing the error, because an expression is expected and a `if {} else {}` is not an expression.

```
const checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("logged-in") === "true" ) {
      return <LoggedInMp/>;
    } else {
      return <NotLoggedInMp/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem please feel free to mark my answer as such :)

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the accepted answer, you could even make this an one-liner:

```
const checkIfUserIsLoggedIn = () => localStorage.getItem("logged-in") ? <LoggedInMp/> : <NotLoggedInMp/>;
```